# Returning an element with a specific attribute JDOM

Tags: java, jdom

i need your help on a particular bit of code.

I have a `document` object in jdom. I also do have a `element` object for the root. Now i want to get a specific element based on the value of an attribute. But what i want to avoid, is to filter through the complete list of children, just to get one element. So is there some kind of way to filter on the value of a document.

Lets say my attribute value is '123'

Now i want the element where the 'id' value is '123'

What is the best way to do this?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [XPath](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/xpath/XPath.html) for that. With the following expression: `//element[@attribute='value']`

Comment: Could you tell me some more about how to use xpath with JDOM, because the jdom docs are not very specific, and neither are the tutorials i find.

Comment: I have never used XPath with JDom, but my guess is that you build an XPath expression using `XPath xpath = XPath.newInstance("//element[@attribute='value']");` and then you evaluate it against your root element (or document, TBC): `xpath.selectNodes(rootElement);`. For more info on XPath expression, google "xpath tutorial", there are plenty of them

Answer (score 2):

If I were confronted with this problem, I would solve it one of two ways:

1) If I only needed to search the elements once to find the element with the particular attribute value, I would do a simple searh. The advantage (and disadvantage) of JDOM is it puts the entire document in memory, so searching through elements is very quick, even if there are many elements. Even if you use XPath (and I admit to being unfamiliar with it, but found the previous answer enlightening), odds are they would be doing the same thing, so this solution is probably no less efficient. In general, using pre-built solutions can save you from having to write code (although in this case your own code would be pretty small), but are usually no more efficient and often less efficient, since you are using a generalized solution that is not specifically tailored to your needs.

2) If I needed to do multiple searches, then I would build a HashMap where the key was the attribute value.

If you think either of these solutions has merit but have some additional questions or would like some sample code, please feel free to email me for further information.